# I'm trying to install all npm modules in ../AppData/Roaming folder. But each time it fails with error code - 4068

Tags: windows, node.js, installation, npm

I'm simply using the following command: "npm install -g". OS: Windows 8.1, CMD is administrator. Error log:

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g' ]
2 info using npm@2.5.1
3 info using node@v0.12.1
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
5 silly cache add args [ '.', null ]
6 verbose cache add spec .
7 silly cache add parsed spec { raw: '.',
7 silly cache add   scope: null,
7 silly cache add   name: null,
7 silly cache add   rawSpec: '.',
7 silly cache add   spec: 'C:\',
7 silly cache add   type: 'local' }
8 error addLocal Could not install C:\
9 verbose stack Error: EISDIR, read
9 verbose stack     at Error (native)
10 verbose cwd C:\
11 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
12 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"   "install" "-g"
13 error node v0.12.1
14 error npm  v2.5.1
15 error code EISDIR
16 error errno -4068
17 error EISDIR, read
18 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
18 error     http://github.com/npm/npm/issues
19 verbose exit [ -4068, true ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you are running `npm install -g` from your `C:` drive. `npm` has *absolutely no idea* what you want it to install unless you:

1. pass it arguments, like how `npm install -g npm` will globally install `npm`
2. run it in a directory that contains a package

Since you are not passing the command any arguments, `npm` assumes you want it to install what is in your current working directory. Since you do not have a package at the root of your `C:` drive, `npm` correctly errors out with the `EISDIR` error ("error: is directory").